# How to check if all items belong to same type using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class  Product
{
public string Name {set; get;}
public string Type {set; get;}
}

public class ProductType
{
public string Name{get;set}
}


var products = GetProducts();
var productTypes = GetProductTypes(); 

bool isValid = products.All(x=>x.Type == ??) // Help required
```

I want to make sure that all products in the 'products' belong to only of the product type.

How could achieve this in linq. Any help is much appreciated I am struck with LINQ stuff ?
Thanks.

Comment: you mean all products are of the same type ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yeah you are correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if all items have the same type as the first item:

```
bool isValid = products.All(x => x.Type == products.First().Type);
```

Comment: @Lamps Please notice it has unnecessary performance cost since every time the anonymous method calls, the `First()` would be execute. Please checkout my answer for a better solution.

Comment: @JeffreyZhao thanks, Joey already pointed out that, I am planning to push Products.First() call out side.

Comment: @Lamps Maybe you need to use `FirstOrDefault()` since the exception would be thrown if the list is empty.

Answer (score 12):

You could use Distinct and Count:

```
isValid = products.Select(x => x.Type).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Joey for the help, but I am preferring dtb's answer.

Comment: That's ok. Although I'd wonder how often a new enumerator is created due to the use of `products.First()` in their code. It could be once per `products` item. But I can't test right now.

Comment: Ah ok thanks joey for the pointing it out, may be I can push the First () call outside and store the value in a local variable?

Comment: This is the slickest way of doing what you're trying to achieve. I would go with this one instead... but that's just my opinion

Answer (score 6):

```
var isValid = products.Select(p => p.Type).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

or

```
var first = products.FirstOrDefault();
var isValid == (first == null) ? true : products.All(p => p.Type == first.Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check the type of each element in LINQ then  -

```
class A{
}

class B{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
       ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
       arr.Add(new A());
       arr.Add(new A());
       arr.Add(new A());
       arr.Add(new B());
       arr.Add(new A());
       int count= arr.ToArray().Count(x=> !x.GetType().Equals(typeof(A)));
}
```

Above example, checks the type of each element in array then gets the count of element from array which are not of class type A.

I hope you have same scenario and hope this helps !!